# How do I determine if my data points are better approximated by a polynomial, exponential or other type of function?

Tags: regression, curve-fitting

I have the following data:

| Benchmark | Size | Run time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test1 | 3153 | 56 |
| test2 | 72410 | 3138 |
| test3 | 8953 | 142 |
| test4 | 151612 | 8056 |
| test5 | 29416 | 668 |
| test6 | 179863 | 9445 |

I want to know what type of function f(x) could best approximate the mapping of size to run time.
Perhaps this is best approximated by an exponential in the form $Runtime(size) = K*N^{size}$, perhaps by a polynomial in the form $Runtime(size) = K*size^2$, or something entirely different.

How do I determine what approximates this data better?

Comment: Usually, mean squared error or mean absolute error of the predictions from the true runtimes.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy do you have a recommended tool to obtain such errors for a given prediction?